# Managing ajax call that returns a lot of data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an an ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    async: false, // you are better off leaving this false
    url: "/api/rest/v1/" 
        + tblMonthlyBudgetCat 
        + "/read?fields=io_uuid,ml_import_key,ml_learning_solution_project_id,ml_monthly_budget_lp,ml_related_budget_categories",
    type: "POST", // change this for PUT to edit records, or DELETE to.. delete.
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(filter), 
    success: function(rec) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

But the table it pulls data from returns a large dataset. Also some data should require permissions to be accessed by some users. So when these users try to run the script it takes a lot of time to execute which actually gives a timeout and google chrome crashes and we need to kill the script.

How to manage:

1) Ajax call with lots of data to run faster

2) Managing/Bypassing permissions to make it run faster

Comment: use ajax pagination that would help to load records.

Comment: How are you checking for user permissions?

Comment: `// you are better off leaving this false` oh really?

Answer (score 0):

You need to rethink your "REST" API. It's not RESTful at all. You've just created a dangerous window into your database directly.

```
/read?fields=io_uuid,ml_import_key,ml_learning_solution_project_id
```

Resources should be a pre-defined thing. There's no harm in having a "summary" and a "full" version (the latter being a subclass of the former) but there should be no concept of specific columnar access. You should not just allow a "random access" window into your database as it is both a performance and security risk.

Design your Resources to be slender enough to be useful but not bloated, use linking (see HATEOAS) for child objects. Do not allow an ORM like Hibernate to pull back huge object graphs. Not only will the data be huge, but you'll likely create an N+1 problem where you issue many (can be tens of thousands) of SQL statements to get back this blob of data.

As another commenter states, use a robust list container that allows for pagination. You can cache the query results on your server side to allow for quick navigation through the pages. The "previous" and "next" page links should be in your list container. You can use this kind of access method to also implement infinite scroll under the hood. Understanding of lists and bundles in REST is fairly simple, but a powerful concept.

Also, note you're using POST for what is a querystring based GET, this is also not great practice as you then cannot cache at the browser layer, even if you wanted to (you may not wish to if the data is quick moving).

Don't push data size management onto your client unless you absolutely MUST. And DEFINITELY don't push redaction or auth+auth onto the client. Your server side should be in charge of this.

You don't have to fully drink the REST koolaid, for example, you may stay more RMI style for your updates (some projects do this), but for reading data, the structure and access paths are so important to get right. They should be almost self-documenting, consistent, cohesive and idempotent. If you do all of this, your API will be easy to use and should not cause your users any problems.

As a final note, your use of the querystring for complex queries could come unstuck on browsers which limit the length, if you do need a really complex query, you may use POST but use a body rather than the querystring.